# How can I change the location of my error, messages?

Tags: php

How do I redirect the error messages from my html_form_send.php back to my registration.php page. Here is what I got, I have my registration.php with the following code:

**registration.php**   (location :   /root/  )

```
<!-- register -->
<div>";
include "$template/email.php";
echo "

</div>
<!-- register -->
```

My email.php links to my html_form_send.php which has the following code:

**email.php**   (location :   /root/models/template  )

```
<form name='htmlform' action='$template/html_form_send.php' method='post' class='form-horizontal well' >

<fieldset>
<legend>Register for an account</legend>

<!-- placeholder for errors -->

<!-- placeholder for errors -->

<br>
<div class='control-group'>
<div class='control-label'>
<label>Name</label>
</div>
<div class='controls'>
<input type='text' placeholder='Type name' name='name' class='input-large'>
```

My html_form_send.php has the following code for an email client that I am using. I want to show the errors on my registration page.

**registration.php**   (location :   /root/models/template  )

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
$email_to = "danielobo2@yahoo.com";

$email_subject = "Registering to blanky-store.net web design account.";


function died($error) {
// your error code can go here
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.";
echo "These errors appear below. <a href='../../../register.php'>Return to previous page</a><br /><br />";
echo $error."<br /><br />";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors. <a href='../../../register.php'>Return to previous page</a><br /><br />";
echo "<a href='../../../register.php'>Return to previous page</a><br /><br />";
die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
!isset($_POST['password'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$password = $_POST['password']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($telephone) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Telephone you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($password) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Password you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Password: ".clean_string($password)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
header("Location: http://blanky-store.net/index.php");
}

?>

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

What I want to do is display the error messages that are appearing on the html_form_send.php and send them to my registration.php instead of displaying on my html_form_send.php page. I have an example of what is doing at this following page   http://blanky-store.net/access/register.php

also what would be the code to combine the email.php page and the html_form_send.php form into one php page?

Answer (score 0):

Store the error message in a session and then redirect the page to  registration.php

Hence check for the session if is set or not. if error message is set then display the session value and after that unset the session value..

Hope it helps..